# apache URL /directory/.pdf Redirects to file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a Directory in Apache with files from which I'm sending direct download links.
folder listing  is off (leads to forbidden page), and CheckSpelling is on for case insensitive URLs.

when typing http://server.example.com/folder/.pdf instead of getting "No Found" or Forbidden, the user is getting the first PDF file on the folder. How can I disable that?

EDIT:
The Directory Configuration is the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/files>
Options None
AllowOverride None
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
</Directory>
```

when entering the following URL: server.example.com/folder/.pdf
the server automatically redirects me to server.example.com/folder/c.pdf

I want the server to serve the files within the directory only when they are explicitly named
in a case-insensitive matter.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify that are you trying
http://server.example.com/folder/.pdf or
http://server.example.com/folder/(filename).pdf

Comment: As always did you check your log files for hints? Mod_speling will of course do minor corrections to guess an URL and not only correct case.

Comment: What is the name of the file that Apache redirects to? Is it something that mod_speling might match against .pdf?

Comment: to clarify: I am typing server.example.com/folder/.pdf (Only extension without filename) and instead of "NO FOUND" I'm getting the first PDF File in an alphabetic order.

Comment: Given that this doesn't seem to be an obvious problem I think you need to add more detail to your question. Could you update the question with what you've tried so far and if possible paste in the relevant parts of the Apache config and entries from the Apache log files.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without using mod_speling?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want mod_speling to do is ignore case then ask for that explicitly by setting CheckCaseOnly to true (see the module docs for details).

Try that and update question if you still have the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.. I tried that, same problem..

Answer (score 0):

can something like this sort you out?

It should ban access to any file starting by dot

I can't confirm that the rule will be interpreted before spelling :-/

```
<Files ~ "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: would be nice to mark it as solution. thx